# How can I make Indicator Session only show my username and not my full name?

Tags: 11.10, panel, indicator, username

My panel has a lot of indicators, and my full name is large. Is there a way to set Ubuntu 11.10 to behave like Ubuntu 11.04 and only show my username?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure that you can just display the username due to [this bug-report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/indicator-session/+bug/812728).

However - if you just want to hide your long real-name then

Install `dconf editor` from software center:

[image]

From the Dash open the `dconf-editor`:

[image]

navigate to the area shown in the picture and uncheck the option shown.

[image]

You will need to do one of the following for the change to take effect:

1. run from a terminal `killall indicator-session-service` or
2. logout and login

Comment: You can just run `killall indicator-session-service` to make the changes take effect, instead of logging out.

Comment: Excellent advice - just tested this and it works great.  Thanks!

Comment: Thanks you. I actually like my name on the indicator. But my user name only, as my full name is too long.

Comment: As the bug report make clear - the devs made this a design decision - so no you will not be able to have the username.  I see in the bug report that someone produced a patch which may give you a hint on what you need to do - you need to compile code to do that.